# VertexLabelStyle not found in Mathematica 8.0.0.0

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-8

I tried to use `VertexLabelStyle`, but seemed not recognized in my system with version number 8.0.0.0. Is this expected or I have missed something? From the online documentation page, I don't see this option was added after version 8.0.0.0; it just says "New in version 8".

Comment: Could you try `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[v, i], {i, 3}], VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 20], ImagePadding -> 20]` in your version and see what you get? This works fine in version 8.0.4. What you are seeing may be due to some fixes between 8.0.0 and 8.0.4

Comment: I also find it does not work in 8.0.0.0

Comment: @kguler: it says `Graph::optx: Unknown option VertexLabelStyle in`

Answer (score 2):

[`VertexLabelStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabelStyle.html) was introduced in *Mathematica* 8.0.1.

The online documentation does not differentiate between the 8.0.x releases, but the in-product documentation does and has no mention of `VertexLabelStyle` in 8.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting the suggestions in the comments above:

In version 8.0.4,

```
  Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1},
  VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[v, i], {i, 3}], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 20], ImagePadding -> 20]
```

works fine. In version 8.0.0 it gives the error message

> ```
> Graph::optx: Unknown option VertexLabelStyle in ...
> ```

So, most likely explanation is:  another version 8.0.0 bug fixed in version 8.0.4.